# SQL Server query, Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server

In query I'm using several `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX`, `LEN` T-SQL functions.

I'm getting an error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Ok, I'm trying to find out which record causes the fail to filter it.

In the WHERE statement, I try:

```
WHERE ...
and mt.id between 1 and 200
```

It fails. Ok, I try to narrow the range, change to:

```
WHERE ...
and mt.id between 1 and 100
```

It works fine. Ok, try the next range:

```
WHERE ...
and mt.id between 100 and 200
```

And it does work fine either! Don't get any error. And it explodes my brain.
Any ideas?

Here's a code I try to run:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM [someTable] mt
  INNER JOIN persons p p.ID = mt.personID
  LEFT JOIN someTable2 pb 
    ON 
      SUBSTRING(pb.shortName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', pb.shortName)) = mt.OSB 
       OR(
      SUBSTRING(mt.OSB, 0, CHARINDEX('/', mt.OSB)) 
    = SUBSTRING(pb.shortName, 0, CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName)) 
     AND
      '0' + SUBSTRING(mt.OSB, CHARINDEX('/', mt.OSB) + 1, LEN(mt.OSB)) 
    = SUBSTRING(pb.shortName, CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName) + 1,
     CHARINDEX(' ', pb.shortName) - CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName) - 1))
WHERE mt.OSB IS NOT null AND mt.shet IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX('/', mt.OSB) > 0  
-- and mt.id between 1 and 200
-- and mt.id between 1 and 100
and mt.id between 100 and 200
order by mt.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about the range.  Your real issue is that one of your substring calls is trying to take more characters than the field has.

SQL Server is not guaranteed to evaluate the records in the same order, so some other record may be being validated when you use the 1-200 range but not be a part of the result set.

For example, the code below would cause an issue if pb.shortName only has one character:

```
SUBSTRING(pb.shortName, CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName) + 1,
                CHARINDEX(' ', pb.shortName) - CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName) - 1)
```

This would be an issue because you depend on both `/` and  being in the string and in a certain order within that string.

Without knowing formatting rules for your app/database, it would be difficult to help you further.

Comment: I use range to find out which record is wrong. The same range of ID fails when it is from 1-200. The same range of id passes well, when I divide it onto two subsets and run them separately. Thats the issue.

Comment: that's the issue, but it isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

between 1 and 200 there is some record which is failing your substring and charindex .try comment/uncomment columns and join to reach that error . don't comment and mt.id between 1 and 200
evaluate each table using same column as in your query between 1 and 200 and see that where the record truncate .
like

```
select SUBSTRING(pb.shortName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', pb.shortName)) ,
       SUBSTRING(pb.shortName, 0, CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName)),

      SUBSTRING(pb.shortName, CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName) + 1,
                CHARINDEX(' ', pb.shortName) - CHARINDEX('/', pb.shortName) - 1)
                from someTable2 pb
                between pb.colname 1 and 200

            similarly run for [someTable] mt
```